# What does "nam" in getspnam, getpwnam, etc. stand for?

Tags: linux, passwd

It looks like "nam" means "item" or "entry" in the context of `getpwnam` or `getspnam`. What exactly does it stand for?

Comment: Check the man pages: [`getspnam(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getspnam), [`getpwnam(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam), etc. You will find their are several overloads by name, including `getpwuid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "by name".

E.g. getpwnam -> get passwd entry by name. Contrast to getpwuid -> get passwd entry by uid.